# what is the set of $\{ k : N\mid kc \}$ given $N$ and $c$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Given $N, c$ such that $1 < c < N$. What is the following set?

$$S=\{ k : 1 \leq k \leq N \text{ and } N \mid kc \}$$

What can we say about this set?

For example, if $\gcd(c,N)=1,$ then we know $S=\{N\}$. what about more general case?

Comment: Have you tried any examples?  If $\text{gcd}(c,N)=d$, then $N/d$ is in the set.  What else?

Comment: what about multiple of $d$?

Comment: redplum, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Don't think in terms of multiples of $d$, more like factors.

Comment: sorry, I meant multiple of N/d

Comment: redplum: Sounds like a good idea.  Can you finish it?

Comment: got it, so S should contain all k<N, s.t. N/d | k.